# Appropriate image size for multi device compatibility in sencha touch

Tags: image, image-processing, sencha-touch, cross-platform

I am developing a app in sencha touch and it has many **dataviews**  with images that are uploaded by administrator in a web app panel.

the red box below in the image indicates the approx size an image will occupy on screen.
[image]

I am confused a bit about a standard minimum image size validation that i should put when administrator uploads the image on backend. I need the image to look good on retina as well as non retina displays.

I read a whole lot of stuff about using `media queries` for serving different images based on screen width and services such as `src.sencha.io` but if i set minimum dimensions on my image such as 800*600 and then display them in the mobile app will that work for different retina and non retina devices ?

Currently what i am doing is that i am compressing whatever size image user uploads to 800 * 600 while maintaining its aspect ratio and then displaying that image in mobile app. But this strategy isn't working out. (Forgive me for something stupid on my part. I am still figuring out how to make images work for all mobile devices)

Anybody with some better advice at what should i be doing so that whenever admin uploads image from web panel, after some processing on it i can create a image that appears good on all screens ?